# Cell indexing in a 2D pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

for school I'm working on a project where I have to save a map using pointers. The map is made out of "cell" structs. When initializing the map I want to use the function index_map to return an adress of a cell so I can change it's properties. However when I try to compile this code the following error occurs:

warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     placeInMap = &(w->map) + stepx*x + stepy*y;

This is my index_map function:

```
`cell* index_map(worldmap* w, int x, int y) 
{
    cell* cellInMap;
    size_t stepx = sizeof(cell)*w->cols;
    size_t stepy = sizeof(cell);
    cellInMap = &(w->map) + stepx*x + stepy*y;
    return cellInMap;
}*`
```

Worldmap is a stuct defined as:

```
`typedef struct worldmap
{
  cell* map;
  unsigned int rows;
  unsigned int cols;
} worldmap;`
```

Cell is a struct defined as:

```
`typedef struct cell
{
    celltype type;
    unsigned int owner;
}cell;`
```

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code. Why do you mention one in your title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`w->map` is a `cell *`. Pointer arithmetics in C already take care of the size of the array element, so to obtain the address of `cell x y` you just add index of row multiplied by the number of columns and the index of the colum:

```
cellInMap = w->map + x*w->col + y;
```

The warning was there because you used `&(w.map)` which is a `cell **` to assign to a `cell *` so with different indexation levels.

Answer (score 0):

w->map has type cell*

&(w->map) has type cell**  ( a pointer to a pointer to a cell )

You're adding to the cell** pointer, and it results in a cell** pointer. Then, you try and assign that to cellInMap which is a cell* pointer. Those are different, and you get the error.

If you add X to a pointer, it advances by the size of what the pointer points at. So, you seem to have additional logic to get the sizeof(cell) which you probably don't need if you add to w->map directly instead of trying to add to &(w->map). I think you're overthinking the problem!

Comment: @SRots If you approve of an answer, the way to go on this website is to upvote it. Click the up arrow at the top left of an answer.